# Получить текущий url iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Возможно ли и как получить текущий url iframe ( отличный от начального src ) ?

Answer (score 1):

### Текущий URL внутри iframe

Если речь идет о переходах пользователя внутри фрейма и попытках получить его текущий url, то это возможно только если вы обращаетесь к фрейму со своего сервера.

В таком случае подойдет:

```
document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.location.href
```

Если же вы хотите получить текущий url, на котором находится пользователь внутри фрейма на другом сервере, то вы не сможете этого сделать из-за SameOrigin Policy.

### Динамически меняющийся src

Если же у вас динамически меняется frame, например через скрипт, то его значение можно получить просто обратившись к `src` вашего фрейма через JS.

**Вот так:**

```
var frame = document.getElementById("frame");
alert(frame.src);
```

### Пример работы всех решений ответа:

Запустите код и посмотрите.

```js
var frame = document.getElementById("frame");
var change = document.getElementById("change");
var check = document.getElementById("check");
var checkURL = document.getElementById("checkURL");

change.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  frame.src = 'https://adudnik.ru/';
});
check.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  alert(frame.src);
});
checkURL.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  alert(frame.contentWindow.location.href);
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 450px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container #change {
  flex: 0 0 48%;
  position: relative;
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  color: #0c5460;
  background-color: #d1ecf1;
  border-color: #bee5eb;
}

.container #check {
  flex: 0 0 48%;
  position: relative;
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  color: #155724;
  background-color: #d4edda;
  border-color: #c3e6cb;
}

.container #checkURL {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  color: #721c24;
  background-color: #f8d7da;
  border-color: #f5c6cb;
}

.container iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button id="change">Изменить url</button>
  <button id="check">Проверить src</button>
  <button id="checkURL">Попробовать получить текущий URL</button>
  <iframe id="frame" src="https://getbootstrap.com/">
</iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Ваш скрипт уже знает src , еще до его изменения. Интересует возможность получить url например после перехода по любой из ссылок в iframe.

Comment: @Taypfoon А, понял. сейчас поправлю ответ. Если кратко - почти наверняка нельзя.

Comment: @Taypfoon поправил ответ и пример кода. Посмотрите.

Comment: и обойти это никак ?

Comment: @Taypfoon если нет доступа к серверу, который вставляется через frame - то никак. Если доступ есть - можно работать с window.postMessage